# Twilio SMS: Using a local number for incoming SMS

Tags: api, twilio, sms

We are looking into Twilio for an SMS campaign where we will be sending an SMS to the customer and according to customer's reply to SMS either 1,2,3 we will update customer data. It looks like we can do this using Twilio REST API using a UK number for example but all our customers are in UAE. We couldn't buy a UAE local number. All we can do is send receive to Dubai customers from UK number. Since it is an international SMS it may lead to customer confusion.

So is it possible to send and receive SMS in Dubai from a local Dubai number (+971 prefix) ?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [available numbers](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/ae), it looks like there are no mobile numbers in the UAE, a requirement for 2-way SMS. You will need to find an alternate channel to perform the survey, for example [email](https://www.twilio.com/sendgrid/email-api). [WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp) may be an option, depending on how popular it is in that country.